# Update rails from 4.2 to 5.0 on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I just installed rails using the awesome rails installer for windows. Unfortunately there is not yet the option available to use the installer for Rails 5, what is the easiest way to upgrade on Windows? I currently have ruby version 2.2.4 and rails 4.2

Comment: The simplest (not necessarily easiest) would be to update your `Gemfile` so it reads `gem 'rails', '5.0'` instead of `gem 'rails', '4.2'` and then run `bundle update rails`. You *might* have to update other gems if there is a conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this tutorial:
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/installing-rails-5-windows
No need to update ruby, because 2.2.2+ versions support new Rails.
Actually you have to run

```
gem install rails --version 5.0.0
```